# Spring Event Handling for prototype components

Tags: java, spring, scope, prototype, event-listener

Let say I have two components X and Y, where X is singleton and Y is not.

when I publish XUpdateEvent, there is no problem, I can catch the event. However, for YUpdateEvent's I cannot catch events. Spring creates new instances for each fired event, not using the already created ones.

So, Should I need to write a custom scope? or EventListener has settings?

To illustrate:

```
@Component
public class X{
 @EventListener
 public void onUpdate(XUpdateEvent event){
 // fine.
 }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Y{
 @EventListener
 public void onUpdate(YUpdateEvent event){
 // calls new instance of Y for each event.
 // Event should be fired for created instances.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Spring creates new instances for each fired event, not using the
>   already created ones

This is what prototype scope means. Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-prototype).

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the
>   creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific
>   bean is made.

If you want that Spring reuses your `Y` instance, declare it as singleton (i.e. define no `@Scope` at all)

Comment: Hi, I have several Y instances that is why they are declared as prototype. What I need is catching event in these already created Y instances, but spring creates new ones and catches in them.

Comment: @Memn what do you mean with **several** Y instances? do you keep a pool of them? does Spring know about it?

Comment: X and Y are some views. X is a view that can be opened once(singleton perfectly fits). Y can be opened one or more. **Does Spring know about it?**  Actually, I don't know. They are only created by Spring's "Autowiring" but is Spring keep track of prototype objects? I am confused about it.

Comment: @Memn As I said, `prototype` means that Spring will create a Bean everytime it needs it. This means that, when an YEvent is fired, an Y Bean will be created, and that's the behaviour you are observing. If you need to have a pool of beans, you have to find another solution.