# Spring Boot - Prototype scope causing bean recreation on event publish

Tags: java, spring-boot, events, publish

I am working on an application that relies on certain beans being prototype-scoped since they need to be re-created from scratch when invoked.  Those beans are essentially 3 tabs in a tab pane : ExpenseTab, IncomeTab and BudgetTab.  The applications uses an event BudgetUpdateEvent which is fired every time there is a change in the ExpenseTab or IncomeTab and the BudgetTab listens to it like so :

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(BudgetUpdateEvent event) 
{
    budgetCalculator.calculateBalance();

    showEntities();
}
```

The BudgetTab bean is annotated as follows :

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Lazy
public class BudgetTab extends EntityTab<BudgetEntry> implements 
ApplicationListener<BudgetUpdateEvent>
{
    //...
}
```

I invoke these beans by passing the TabPane object to the constructor as follows :

```
budgetTab = springContext.getBean(BudgetTab.class, tabPane, budgetEntryRepo.findAll());
```

The TabPane object is not and cannot be a Bean.  This is important to understand for what the issue is.

When i fire the event from say the ExpenseTab, i do it as follows :

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

publisher.publishEvent(new BudgetUpdateEvent(this));
```

For some reason, if the BudgetTab is marked as prototype scoped, i get an exception when publishing this event which indicates to me that Spring is recreating a new instance of this bean :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'budgetTab' defined in file [C:\Users\607337\Documents\EclipseProjects\Budget\target\classes\com\mdenis\budget\components\tabs\BudgetTab.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javafx.scene.control.TabPane' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:239)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
at com.mdenis.budget.components.tabs.ExpenseTab.deleteEntity(ExpenseTab.java:107)
at com.mdenis.budget.components.tabs.EntityTab.lambda$initButtons$4(EntityTab.java:235)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javafx.scene.control.TabPane' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1658)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
```

When i remove the prototype scope this behavior stops and the BudgetTab is updated properly but then i NEED the prototype scope for other aspects of this bean to work correctly.

Bottom line is : Why is Spring re-instantiating a prototype-scoped bean when firing an event for which said bean listens to?

Comment: I just found this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368341/spring-event-handling-for-prototype-components

Does this mean there is no way around bean-recreation when firing my event if the bean is prototype-scoped and I need to rework my code to make it a singleton?

Comment: I managed to rewrite a few things so the beans no longer need to be prototype-scoped.  Still, seems strange that a bean would be completely recreated when publishing an event for which it listens...